# Modificar atributos de elementos HTML creados dinamicamente con JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

En mi pagina web hago una petición al servidor `PHP` con `AJAX`, y traigo unos enlaces ya creados en `PHP`. Todo bien hasta aquí, pero el problema es que a dichos enlaces le quiero cambiar el `href` con `JavaScipt`, pero no me cambia la url de los enlaces, este es mi código:

```
var theLinks = document.querySelectorAll(".paginacion a");

  theLinks.forEach(function(element, index) {
    element.href = "http://es.stackoverflow.com";
  });
```

Este problema solo le pasa a los enlaces traídos por AJAX (tienen la clase "paginación"), ya que si intento cambiar los `href` de los enlaces que están estéticamente en la pagina, los que NO fueron traídos por `AJAX`, si les cambia el `href`. Por ejemplo si ejecuto el código siguiente en lugar del anterior, me cambia la url de todos los enlaces, excepto los que tienen la clase `paginacion`.

```
var theLinks = document.querySelectorAll("a");

      theLinks.forEach(function(element, index) {
        element.href = "http://es.stackoverflow.com";
      });
```

Espero y me puedan ayudar, ya tengo varios días dando le vuelta al código y no encuentro una solución, gracias.

Comment: Puedas dar un ejemplo del código HTML que te genera tu AJAX ?

Comment: Ademas del llamado al AJAX y La invocacion a tu js.

Comment: ¿No habrá más bien un problema de lógica o de planteamiento? Parece que el código que cambia los enlaces lo hace cuando todavía éstos no existen en el DOM, pues si existieran los cambiaría. Otra cosa que suena extraña es que los traigas por Ajax y luego debas cambiarlos. ¿Por qué no los escribes como deben ser desde el principio? ¿Por qué los cambias luego?

Comment: si ese era el problema, el orden en que se ejecutaban las funciones. Como AJAX es asíncrono, se ejecutaba el método de modificar las urls antes de que terminara la petición AJAX. Solo desactive esa propiedad, y todo funciona a la perfección.

Answer (score 0):

Tu selector es incorrecto.  Intentalo asi:

```
var theLinks = document.querySelectorAll("a.paginacion");  

theLinks.forEach(function(element, index) {
    element.href = "http://es.stackoverflow.com";
  });
```

Comment: pero si le aplico el selector a todos los enlaces de la página, igual solo le cambia el href  a los que no tienen dicha clase

Comment: En donde intentas hacer el cambio?  Es una funcion?

Comment: si, dentro de una función que se ejecuta en un evento 'click''

Comment: Intenta poner el `click` handler dentro de la funcion success del Ajax

Answer (score 0):

El problema era que no considere la asincronidad de AJAX, y ejecutaba la función de modificar los `href` aunque la petición AJAX que traía los enlaces no se terminara de ejecutar. Lo que hice fue solo cambiar a `false` el ultimo parámetro del método `open` del `XMLHttpRequest()`:

```
  xhr.open("post", "admin/ajax/paginacion.php", false);
```

Gracias a todos por aportar algo.